# reliability scale test (omega function as proposed by McDonald), how to interpret the output?

Tags: reliability

I've used a 27 item questionnaire on barriers to physical activity. Scoring system was used to indicate how likely each statement/question was considered to be a barrier (very likely=3, somewhat likely=2, somewhat unlikely=1, very unlikely=0). Scores of the three theme-related questions were added up to provide a total for each category of barriers i.e 27 questions divided by 3= 9 barrier categories . Possible scores for each barrier category ranged from 0-9.

I've used the omega function to determine reliability of the scale. I have no clue how to interpret the following output. please help me. Not sure what to report ???

### Omega

### Call: omega(m = EXL_barriers)

### Alpha: 0.51

### G.6: 0.57

### Omega Hierarchical: 0.29

### Omega H asymptotic: 0.45

### Omega Total 0.66

## #

### Schmid Leiman Factor loadings greater than 0.2

### g F1* F2* F3* h2 u2 p2

### Lack.of.time 0.79 0.63 0.37 0.99

### Lack.of.social.support 0.47 0.28 0.72 0.03

### Lack.of.energey 0.64 0.22 0.47 0.53 0.87

### Lack.of.willpower 0.63 0.44 0.56 0.09

### Fear.of.enjury- 0.68 0.55 0.45 0.06

### Lack.of.skills 0.80 0.67 0.33 0.00

### Lack.of.resources 0.31 0.51 0.32 0.68 0.00

### Religious- 0.04 0.96 0.93

### Environmental 0.01 0.99 0.83

### With eigenvalues of:

### g F1* F2* F3*

### 1.15 1.44 0.00 0.81

## #

### general/max 0.8 max/min = 713.37

### mean percent general = 0.42 with sd = 0.46 and cv of 1.09

### Explained Common Variance of the general factor = 0.34

## #

### The degrees of freedom are 12 and the fit is 0.06

### The number of observations was 305 with Chi Square = 16.64 with prob < 0.16

### The root mean square of the residuals is 0.03

### The df corrected root mean square of the residuals is 0.05

### RMSEA index = 0.037 and the 10 % confidence intervals are 0 0.073

### BIC = -52.01

## #

### Compare this with the adequacy of just a general factor and no group factors

### The degrees of freedom for just the general factor are 27 and the fit is 0.89

### The number of observations was 305 with Chi Square = 267.92 with prob < 1.7e-41

### The root mean square of the residuals is 0.16

### The df corrected root mean square of the residuals is 0.18

## #

### RMSEA index = 0.173 and the 10 % confidence intervals are 0.153 0.19

### BIC = 113.47

## #

### Measures of factor score adequacy

### g F1* F2* F3*

### Correlation of scores with factors 0.85 0.87 0.04 0.78

### Multiple R square of scores with factors 0.72 0.76 0.00 0.61

### Minimum correlation of factor score estimates 0.43 0.53 -1.00 0.22

### Total, General and Subset omega for each subset

### g F1* F2* F3*

### Omega total for total scores and subscales 0.66 0.69 NA 0.43

### Omega general for total scores and subscales 0.29 0.31 NA 0.02

### Omega group for total scores and subscales 0.36 0.38 NA 0.41